# Is "ambiguate" a word, or is there a word with a similar meaning?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I want to say something along the lines of "obscure", such as "He obscured the details" but I want it to capture the idea that the obscurity lies in the ambiguous nature of his description.

Comment: Do you want to imply deliberate or unintentional ambiguity?

Comment: deliberate ambiguity

Comment: funny thing about english - there are often "negative forms" of words with no corresponding positive form, e.g. *disambiguate*

Comment: Is this for some kind of formal writing? If no, then just go ahead and use _ambiguate_ (set it off in ‘scare quotes’ if you will). It's a perfectly clear and obvious word, and no one will have any doubts as to what it means in context. Just because it hasn't made it into the dictionaries and isn't very common doesn't mean it's not usable and perfectly cromulent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good word for this is [obfuscate](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+obfuscate):

> he **obfuscated** the details.

It implies intentionality, as well as hiding "in plain sight".

From [vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/obfuscate):

> Some people are experts at obfuscating the truth by being evasive,
>   unclear, or obscure in the telling of the facts. The people who are
>   good at obfuscating would include defense lawyers and teenagers asked
>   about their plans for Saturday night.
>
> Although the verb obfuscate can be used in any case where something is
>   darkened, less clear, or more obscure, it is most frequently used in
>   reference to things like ideas, facts, issues, or the truth. The usual
>   implied meaning is that this obfuscation is done deliberately.
>   Politicians often obfuscate the truth about the issues to win support
>   for their positions so they can win elections.

Comment: +1; this is a particularly common usage in computer science.

Comment: Computer Science (primarily): One could argue that `obfuscate` is not quite the same thing as `to make ambiguous` -- you can `obfuscate` a class name from `Image` to `fj38gjj`, however, it would be `ambiguous` (not `obfuscatory`) as to whether you were referring to `PIL.Image` or `imglib.Image`. I'd go with the `ambiguate:disambiguate::obfuscate:deobfuscate` when exactness of meaning matters. All that said, I expect that neither `ambiguate` nor `deobfuscate` see much usage outside of Computer Science and other fields where name/meaning exactness really **really** matters **A LOT**.

Comment: *Obfuscate* is not an antonym for *disambiguate*; rather, it is an antonym for *clarify*; *disambiguation* is only one kind of *clarification*.

Comment: An example is being asked if you are for "equality of opportunity" or "equality of outcomes", but labeling your position "for equality". It's more an intentional refusal to distinguish, that I don't think obfuscate quite relays.

Answer (score 0):

My gut reflex was that 'ambiguate' is not a word, and the Internet and dictionary seem to agree. The only place I've found a reasonable selection of quotes with the word is [here](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/_/search/Search.aspx?By=0&SearchBy=0&q=Ambiguate).

Do you care about it being a verb? If not, you could go with:

> He gave us **ambiguous/inconclusive/polysemous/equivocal/ambivalent** details.

But I think using "ambiguous" might be your best shot, since it's the most readily understood one - if you can use an adjective... Perhaps you could give us more context?

Answer (score 0):

How about "He **muddled** the details."

*Obscure* can have this meaning, but sometimes it has the meaning of *hiding* the details. *Muddle* implies that you can see the details fine, you just can't figure out what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

The term "disambiguation" has come into common usage thanks to Wikipedia, where disambiguation refers to the process of resolving conflicts that arise when a single term is used in two different ways.

I wish that there were a term "ambiguate" to refer to its opposite.  I suspect the reason there's not such a term is that disambiguation is occasionally necessary in situations where ambiguity evolves unintentionally.

I think obfuscate is a perfectly good word to describe situations where there is a malicious and willful intent to create ambiguity.

But there is another way that ambiguity can be created and one that I encounter frequently a professional context.  It happens when a word having a well-established definition or meaning, is used in a different way, or in a different context, such that its original meaning is no longer clear.

Unfortunately certain practitioners of the engineering profession do this sort of thing all the time.  They are all for "functionality" and don't care much for established meanings.  If they find a good use for an already-existing word in a different context, they'll go ahead and use it, with no regard for its former meaning.  As long as it works for them, it's fine.   It's up to the rest of us to sort things out.

Comment: The word disambiguation has been in use a lot longer than Wikipaedia has existed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a perfectly good word, but I also think it is a neologism.

I don't think it is actually the right word for your circumstances, but I think the closest established word to "ambiguate" is "conflate".

Comment: What dictionary gave you the idea that *conflate* is a better choice than the already-suggested *obfuscate* or *muddle*, or indeed than *confuse*?

Comment: *Obfuscate* simply is not the right word; it is an antonym for *clarify*, which is less precise than *disambiguate*. *Confuse* can mean "make distinct things hard to distinguish," but it has other meanings as well (such as "make hard to understand"), while *conflate* only means "combine distinct things as though they were the same."