# Word meaning "To try and make an objective fact subjective"

Tags: synonyms

For example:

> Person 1: The sky is blue.
>
> Person 2: Not necessarily, Person X sees the sky as grey because they are colorblind.

or

> Person 1: The sky is blue.
>
> Person 2: I don't believe that the sky is blue because you cheated on your wife.

For the second example, I'm not interested in the character appeal logical fallacy aspect. Also, please take for granted that the sky being blue is an objective fact.

*Subjectification* is a word but it doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: You might as well just use a gender-specific *singular* pronoun and say “because ***he** is* colorblind,” since most colorblind humans are male.

Comment: The phrase "alternative facts" comes to mind, but I don't think it's quite right for this usage.

Comment: Distortion hits the mark for me, perhaps you have other words in mind. If a fact that occurred in the past "Didn't happen," I call that rewriting history.

Comment: this prior question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160940/is-ambiguate-a-word-or-is-there-a-word-with-a-similar-meaning offers a couple options  (obfuscate and muddle)  I was trying to see if there was a verb form for ambiguous and stumbled upon it.

Comment: *Relativize* catches a lot of it.

Comment: Hard to answer (and hard to judge what's been offered) without a sample sentence.  Could you write a sentence with a blank in the place where the special word will go?